# Regexp dynamic variable

Tags: regex, bash, cron, grep

I have a crontab file named `mycronfile`:

```
#30 07 03 09 RAB root bash /media/data/test1.sh
#* * * * * root bash /media/data/test2.sh
30 07 * * * root bash /media/data/test3.sh
```

I am trying to add new lines to it but only if they don't already exist. This my code :

```
while read $line; do
  com1=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $8 }')
  com2=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $7 }')
  fullCom=$(echo "$com2 $com1")
  fixMin=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }')
  fixHour=$(echo $line | awk   '{ print $2 }')
  fixDate=$(echo $line | awk   '{ print $3 }')
  fixMonth=$(echo $line | awk   '{ print $4 }')

  actv=`echo "$fixMin $fixHour $fixDate $fixMonth $fixDay $user $fullCom"`

  if grep "$actv" tempcron; then
    echo "data in tempcron exist"
    echo "$actv" > /dev/null
  else
    echo "data input into file"
    echo "$actv >> tempcron"
  fi
done < myfilecron
```

Every time I execute the script, data in `tempcron` is always duplicated.  Of course I need to `grep` from `mycronfile` with the right pattern to avoid duplication. But how to `grep` it with regular expression? Because problem come when line contain asterisk (*).

Comment: So you want to make sure that `$var` contains no numbers?

Comment: It can be contain number or no number. I don't have any problem if value contain number, but the problem come when value contain no number.

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are trying to do. Can you try to explain it more clearly?

Comment: I have `crontab` file. And as you know, crontab doesn't always contain number right? There is combination between `#-number` or `*/number` or any other combination. I `read` each line from crontab and store into variable. All I trying to do is `grep` line, store into variable then  redirect output from variable value into other `temporary file`.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it as clear as possible. Thanks.

Comment: I have updating my question sir. I hope it clear enough to help  you understand my question.

Comment: What do you want to do with the lines that are commented out in your crontab file? What are the contents of `tempcron`? Is `myfilecron` supposed to be the same as `mycronfile`?

Answer (score 2):

A rewrite:

```
while read min hr date mon day user cmd; do
    actv="$min $hr $date $mon $day $user $cmd"   # only purpose I can see here
                                                 # is to fix the spaces    
    if grep -Fq "$actv" tempcron; then
        echo "data in tempcron exist"
    else
        echo "data input into file"
        echo "$actv >> tempcron"
    fi
done < myfilecron
```

The main problem is that the $actv string contains `*` characters, which are regular expression quantifiers. You weren't telling grep to search for a plain string, you were giving a regex pattern that didn't match.

The other big problem with your script: `while read $line` -- you give `read` one or more variable **names** not a variable **values**